# When to use drush_log() or drush_set_error()?

Tags: drush

I just trying to show an error message with drush and I see that you can achieve this with

```
drush_set_error('NON_EXISTENT', 'Message');
```

and with

```
drush_log('Message', 'error');
```

In both cases you will see the same error message, I read the functions documentation but I can't figure out are the differences between they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should avoid using the status code 'error' when calling `drush_log` directly. Use `drush_log` to signal non-terminal events, usually with a status code of `warning` or `notice`.

If a function fails and cannot continue, the best thing to do is to exit with `return drush_set_error(...);`. This sets internal state, so that Drush knows that there was an unrecoverable error, and calls through to `drush_log('Message', 'error');`.